# Using cosine similarity for classifying documents

Tags: nlp, classification, data-science, text-mining, cosine-similarity

I have a set of files for five different categories and most of them are not labelled correctly.Objective is to predict the correct category of the file whenever the same is uploaded.I used cosine similarity along with tf -idf to predict the class of the document with which cosine similarity is the maximum as of now i am getting good results but really not sure how well this will work down the road. Also why isnt cosine similarity used in building document classifiers instead of machine learning models when the categories of files are labelled correctly?Would really appreciate your feedback on my approach as well as your answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity?wprov=sfla1) is used for calculating the angle between two n-dimensional vectors. These vectors are mostly produced by Embeddings. They are pretrained models which produce word embeddings or fixed size vectors.

> Cosine similarity is mostly used with vectors produced by word
>   embeddings. If you are using something like Doc2Vec, then you get a
>   vector for the whole document. These vectors could be categorized by
>   using cosine similarity.

**In your case, you should try a LSTM text classifier using Embedding layers. 1D Convolution layers can also be useful.**

Also, referring to TF-IDF, it is useful for text classification which is dependent on certain words in the corpus. The words with higher term frequency and less document frequency have a higher TF-IDF score. The model learns to classify texts based on such scores.

> In most cases, RNNs are the best to classify texts. The use of pretrained embeddings makes the model efficient.

Also, not the least, you can give Bayes text classification a try. It has been super useful in spam classification.

**Tip:**

You can implement the above methods with each other, creating a text classification system. Following the process like,

1. Generate embeddings from Doc2Vec.
2. Comparing the similarity of the input with other texts and thereby determine its class.
3. Using the embedding in a  LSTM network to produce class probabilities.
4. Apply Bayes text classification.

The steps 2 , 3 , 4 give three predictions. If the majority prediction was CLASS1, then we can make the output of the system as CLASS1!.

Comment: Doc2vec+cosine similarity was supposed to be my next approach if tfidf+cosine similarity didnt work considering the fact that doc2vec will take the semantic nature of the document into account .None the less will definitely give it a try as far as naive bayes is concerned , the labels are not correct making it an unsupervised problem(so dont really understand how naive bayes will perform).

Comment: So i manually labelled few files, took out unique keywords of 10 files belonging to each category appended them in a list then word2vec and cosibe similarity. The other approach i had in mind was clustering but i frankly dont want to involve machine learning if cosine similarity works well and will definitely scale nicely .Let's see, Thank you so much for your feedback , really appreciate it :)